# How do I write a program in C that counts the number of numbers as an argument?

Tags: c, arguments

I'm just toying with the

```
  int main(int argc, int *argv[void])
```

function, and im trying to make a program that reads the *number of number arguments*.

Theoretically (in my own crazy delusional mind), this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int count;
 printf("%d\n", sizeof(int));
}
```

but no matter what i put as the argument in the command line, i always get 4 (4 bytes in a word?)

How can I tweak this code a little so that when i type

```
./program 9 8 2 7 4 3 1
```

i get:

```
7
```

much appreciated!

Comment: [**`sizeof`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/sizeof) doesn't do what you think it does. You need a loop.

Comment: You're printing the size of an `int`, which happens to be 4 bytes on your computer. Why did you think that would produce anything having to do with the number of arguments you passed on the command line?

Comment: I think you can simply print `argc - 1`.

Comment: not sure how you got 7, that's not even a power of 2, i bet no computer stores ints at 7 bytes long

Comment: @self he said he "wants it" to say `7` the number of arguments supplied.

Comment: What about non-number arguments? What do you want to get from `./program 9 8 2 foo bar 11 5`? What about `./program -7 3.14159265 0x8e `?

Comment: What do you expect to print for `./program 9 x "1 2 3"`?

Comment: `argv[void]` <- wut

Comment: `if(argc > 1)printf("%d\n", argc - 1);` (-:

Comment: thanks user3078414, worked perfectly! would work really nice as an answer with a full explanation of what it did, but no need

Answer (score 5):

`argc` represents the number of command line arguments passed in. You can use that as an index into the second argument to main, `argv`. If you want all the arguments not including the first one (the program name), then you'll need to decrement argc, and increment argv.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    /*
     * forget about the program name.
     */
    argv++;
    argc--;

    int i;
    unsigned int totalNumbers = 0;

    printf("Total number of arguments: %d\n", argc);

    for(i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        printf("argv[%d]=%s\n", i, argv[i]);

        errno = 0;
        long num = strtol(argv[i], NULL, 10);
        if(!(num == 0L && errno == EINVAL))
            totalNumbers++;

    }
    printf("Total number of numeric arguments: %u\n", 
        totalNumbers);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that `argc` also counts the the name of the executable itself.

Comment: And then you need to call `strtol()` to verify that each number is actually a number and not something else...

Comment: Hey, i forgot that part, but check it now. `atoi` isn't a very good choice because it returns 0 regardless if it is errored or not. I chose strtol because it sets errno.

Comment: `errno` doesn't reset itself.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thanks. I was thinking about resetting it.

Comment: Hmmm.. I always seems to get `argc==totalNumbers` with your code on OpenBSD, but not on OS X. Weird. I will look into that.

Comment: i'm on a OS x currently

Comment: Ah, on OpenBSD, `EINVAL` is set if "The value of base was neither between 2 and 36 inclusive nor the special value 0."  While on OS X it says "The value of base is not supported or no conversion could be performed (*the last feature is not portable across all platforms*)."   (that's reading the strtol(3) manual)

Comment: what does glibc do? It seems hard to verify strtol hasn't errored out

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out in the comments, `sizeof` doesn't do quite what you think it does.

You are given `argc` and `argv`.  The second of these is an array of string corresponding to the things on the command line. This `argv` array of strings is `argc` long, and the first element of it is likely to hold the name of the executable program.

You need to loop through the remaining elements of `argv` (if there are any) and see which ones are numbers, as opposed to non-numbers.

To check if a string is a number or not, we can use `strtol()` (from `stdlib.h`) to try to convert it into a `long`.  If the conversion fails, it's not a number. If you'd like to accept floating point values, then use `strtod()` instead, it works *almost* in the same way (doesn't take the last argument that `strtol()` does).  **EDIT**: I actually changed the code to use `strtod()` instead since it accepts a larger variety of "numbers".

The conversion fails if the string is empty from the start, or if the pointer that we supply to the function (`endptr`) doesn't point to the very end of the string after calling it.

Then, if the argument is a number, simply count it, and at the end tell the user what he or she probably already knew.

What you're doing here is called *validating user input* and it's a *really good thing to know how to do*. Don't trust users to give you numbers just because you ask them to. Check to see if they really *are* numbers by reading in strings and trying to convert them.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

bool is_number(const char *string)
{
    char *endptr;

    strtod(string, &endptr);

    return (*string != '\0' && *endptr == '\0');
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i;
    int numcount = 0;

    for (i = 1; i < argc; ++i) {
        if (is_number(argv[i]))
            numcount++;
    }

    printf("There were %d numbers on the command line\n", numcount);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Running it:

```
$ /a.out 1 2 3 a b c -.5 +20 1e20
There were 6 numbers on the command line

$ ./a.out nt 12 ,e2 2 21n 1 -8
There were 4 numbers on the command line
```